# Open Modal through a href with get fundction

Tags: modal-dialog

I have a table with rows of records. Each record has a unique id. On each row is a button for a modal to open. I want to create a href that has the id for that record to open in the modal.
Here is an example of what works without the modal that opens in a new window.

```
<a href="https://website.com/?page=wpda&table_name=wpdw_cases&action=edit
&pat_id=$$pat_id$$&patient_name=$$patient_name$$&user_login=$$user_login$$" target="_blank"><button>Detail</button></a>
```

Here is the basic Modal link I am using:

```
<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal"><button>Detail</button></a>
```

How do I add &pat_id=$$pat_id$$ to the above modal that will open that record in the modal for the record row?

Thanks for your help!